# training loss increases over time despite of a tiny learning rate

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm playing with CIFAR-10 dataset using ResNet-50 on Keras with Tensorflow backend, but I ran into a very strange training pattern, where the model loss decreased first, and then started to increase until it plateaued/stuck at a single value due to almost 0 learning rate. Correspondingly, the model accuracy increased first, and then started to decrease until it plateaued at 10% (aka random guess). I wonder what is going wrong?

Typically this U shaped pattern happens with a learning rate that is too large (like [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/324896/training-loss-increases-with-time?newreg=3d838414b18e47d2b4639cf771b1d92c)), but it is not the case here. This pattern also doesn't' look like a classic "over-fitting" as both the training and validation loss increase over time. In the answer to the above linked [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/324896/training-loss-increases-with-time), someone mentioned that if Adam optimizer is used, loss may explode under small learning rate when local minimum is exceeded, I'm not sure I can follow what is said there, and also I'm using SGD with weight decay instead of Adam.

Specifically for the training set up, I used resent50 with random initialization, SGD optimizer with 0.9 momentum and a weight decay of 0.0001 using [decoupled weight decay regularization](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/opti), batch-size 64, initial learning_rate 0.01 which declined by a factor of 0.5 with each 10 epochs of non-decreasing validation loss.

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False,
                                        weights=None,pooling='avg', 
                                        input_shape=(32,32,3))
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([base_model,
                         prediction_layer])
SGDW = tfa.optimizers.extend_with_decoupled_weight_decay(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD)
optimizer = SGDW(weight_decay=0.0001, learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=["accuracy"])
reduce_lr= tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',factor=0.5, patience=10)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, 
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_batches, epochs=250, 
      validation_data=validation_batches,
      callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your model and training loop code? The issue is difficult to tell from the loss plots alone. Can you also double check that your training and test sets are randomly shuffled (i.e. your model isn't training entirely on a single class then is exposed to another class it has never seen)?

Comment: I've added the code snippet. I've double checked the data loading process. The data were shuffled when being loaded, and shuffled again when being batched. It's only under this specific model set up will I run into this issue. If I change optimizer, this issue doesn't appear, so I don't think the problem is related to data shuffle.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior when the weight decay is removed?

Comment: No. When weight decay is removed, the training becomes normal. It may seem like weight decay is the cause. But on a side note, when I switch to Adam, I don't observe this pattern, with or without weight decay. So the question may boil down to why SGD + weight decay causes this pattern?

Comment: I'm not certain, but in the Tensorflow docs (the second "Note") they say to manually decay the weight decay if you're also decaying the learning rate: https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/weight_decay_optimizers/DecoupledWeightDecayExtension

Comment: Yeah I notice that too. I'm not sure if that's the reason, especially given that this pattern is only observed for SGD but not for Adam. If I turn off either the learning_rate decay, or the weight decay, then this pattern disappear, but meanwhile the validation accuracy were not as high (below 80%). I guess I'm still looking for an explanation for this pattern, but thanks for your replies.